# Arduino Nano input voltage

Tags: arduino-nano

Can I supply an Arduino Nano 5 V 1 A unregulated in pin 27?

It has a PIR sensor, a LDR sensor and switch drive high power MOSFET trigger module connected to it.

Comment: Probably not. Pin 27 is the 5V pin. That is the voltage at which the microcontroller runs. It is safer to use the VIN pin with 7.5v, although sometimes 5v is applied to the 5v pin, but that could destroy the voltage regulator. The most dangerous part is the word "unregulated". Does that mean that it can be anything between 4 and 7v? Do not apply that to the 5v pin.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!